# Как выполнить make, находясь в другой дирректории?

Tags: linux, vim, makefile

Возможно ли это? Не хочу тратить время на выход из vim, команду cd. Также не хочу держать открытыми несколько окон.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Ключи:
>   -C КАТАЛОГ, --directory=КАТАЛОГ
>                   Перейти в КАТАЛОГ перед выполнением действий.

```
make -C /путь/к/каталогу
```